# sql server summarise or group data

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have an extract in SQL and I would like to group / Rank data in the format as shown in the table below in the desired output column. My question is how do to i achive this. I have tried Rank and Dense rank function but it is not giving me the desired result.

Cusomter_Id|    Rno | Start_Dt  | End_Dt |  PM_Status|Desired_Output
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1609    |1  |02/10/2014 |08/10/2014 |VD |1 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1609    |2  |09/10/2014 |02/11/2014 |CC |2 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1609    |3  |03/11/2014 |04/11/2014 |CC |2  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1609    |4  |05/11/2014 |27/01/2015 |FD |3 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1609    |5  |28/01/2015 |02/02/2015 |CC |4 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1609    |6  |03/02/2015 |09/02/2015 |CC |4 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1609    |7  |10/02/2015 |31/12/9999 |CC |4 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

I hope the above data make sense any questions please let me know.

Many thanks for looking inot my query.

Comment: I have a question - what are you trying to do?  Please, edit your question and describe what you are trying to accomplish; imagine you are reading your question from our perspective, and try to explain the logic behind your desired results.

Comment: Sorry for not been clear in describing my question. I would like to rank /group the data based on the PM_Status in order to achive the min and max of each ocurance of PM_Status. For example if you see PM_Status 'CC' it has occured in two different time period if i Group by just PM_Status to get min and max of start and end dt of each PM_Status it is not right. As there is another PM_status by 'FD' in betwen. Ideally if I can rank the occurance of PM_Status as shown in desired_output this will help me achive my result where in i can group by desired _output with min and max of start and end dt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to find your grouping and achieve your desired results:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    Customer_Id INT,
    Rno INT,
    Start_Dt DATE,
    End_Dt DATE,
    PM_Status VARCHAR(5),
    Desired INT
)
INSERT @Data VALUES
    (1609, 1, '2/10/2014', '10/8/2014', 'VD', 1),
    (1609, 2, '10/9/2014', '11/2/2014', 'CC', 2),
    (1609, 3, '11/3/2014', '11/4/2014', 'CC', 2),
    (1609, 4, '11/5/2014', '1/27/2014', 'FD', 3),
    (1609, 5, '1/28/2015', '2/2/2015', 'CC', 4),
    (1609, 6, '2/3/2015', '2/9/2015', 'CC', 4),
    (1609, 7, '2/10/2015', NULL, 'CC', 4)

; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Customer_id,
        Rno,
        Start_Dt,
        End_Dt,
        PM_Status,
        Desired,
        1 AS Actual
    FROM @Data
    WHERE RNo = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        SRC.Customer_id,
        SRC.Rno,
        SRC.Start_Dt,
        SRC.End_Dt,
        SRC.PM_Status,
        SRC.Desired,
        CASE WHEN CTE.PM_Status <> SRC.PM_Status 
            THEN CTE.Actual + 1 ELSE CTE.Actual END
    FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN @Data SRC
            ON SRC.Customer_Id = CTE.Customer_Id
                AND SRC.Rno = CTE.Rno + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
Customer_id Rno         Start_Dt   End_Dt     PM_Status Desired     Actual
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------- -----------
1609        1           2014-02-10 2014-10-08 VD        1           1
1609        2           2014-10-09 2014-11-02 CC        2           2
1609        3           2014-11-03 2014-11-04 CC        2           2
1609        4           2014-11-05 2014-01-27 FD        3           3
1609        5           2015-01-28 2015-02-02 CC        4           4
1609        6           2015-02-03 2015-02-09 CC        4           4
1609        7           2015-02-10 NULL       CC        4           4
```

Comment: Thanks very much Jason , that was spot on.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Feel free to upvote or accept this as your answer if you are good with it.

Comment: Just click the left up arrow next to my answer. It's part of what helps this site be successful to show accepted (clicking the checkmark next to the answer) and upvoting (arrow up next to answer) so that others with similar questions can find your question and hopefully help them, too.